# How can I access my dslr through android smartphone using USB cable

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'd like to create my own android app which would be a remote device for my camera DSLR through USB cable.

Is there any library to do so?
Could you possibly link me some tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check following links, I haven't tried any these projects. But I think it will guide you well.

- [Android_USB_PTP_Lib](https://github.com/terencehonles/Android_USB_PTP_Lib)
- [OpenSourcePhotography](https://github.com/ibaaj/awesome-OpenSourcePhotography)
- [remoteyourcam-usb](https://github.com/crazymaik/remoteyourcam-usb)

Comment: sweet! it looks very promising, I will check them all :)

Comment: Awesome... 
Best of luck
If it works accept the answer.

Comment: In these links I found exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks @Nakul !!!
(https://github.com/crazymaik/remoteyourcam-usb)

Comment: Awesome, I will update the answer to add this link too. I hope you won't mind.